# *** buffer overflow detected ***: php terminated

Tags: linux

I have dedicated server with WHM when am trying to run any script from the command line am getting the following error but when am running the same script from Root it's run correctly :

Please help :)

```html
*** buffer overflow detected ***: php terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x76e9e6f9e7f7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x1006e0)[0x76e9e6f9c6e0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0xffb39)[0x76e9e6f9bb39]
/lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_default_xsputn+0xc9)[0x76e9e6f104a9]
/lib64/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x64f)[0x76e9e6ee048f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0x9d)[0x76e9e6f9bbdd]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x7f)[0x76e9e6f9bb1f]
php[0x403328]
php[0x4020e9]
php[0x40171f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x76e9e6ebad1d]
php[0x4011e9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 565253                             /usr/local/bin/php
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 09:02 565253                             /usr/local/bin/php
00605000-01b81000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
01b81000-01ba2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
76e9e6c86000-76e9e6c9c000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 2727991                    /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
76e9e6c9c000-76e9e6e9b000 ---p 00016000 09:02 2727991                    /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
76e9e6e9b000-76e9e6e9c000 rw-p 00015000 09:02 2727991                    /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
76e9e6e9c000-76e9e7026000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 2728045                    /lib64/libc-2.12.so
76e9e7026000-76e9e7226000 ---p 0018a000 09:02 2728045                    /lib64/libc-2.12.so
76e9e7226000-76e9e722a000 r--p 0018a000 09:02 2728045                    /lib64/libc-2.12.so
76e9e722a000-76e9e722c000 rw-p 0018e000 09:02 2728045                    /lib64/libc-2.12.so
76e9e722c000-76e9e7230000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
76e9e7230000-76e9e724f000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 5392297                    /usr/lib64/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
76e9e724f000-76e9e744e000 ---p 0001f000 09:02 5392297                    /usr/lib64/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
76e9e744e000-76e9e744f000 rw-p 0001e000 09:02 5392297                    /usr/lib64/libyaml-0.so.2.0.4
76e9e744f000-76e9e746f000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 2727958                    /lib64/ld-2.12.so
76e9e7660000-76e9e7663000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
76e9e766b000-76e9e766e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
76e9e766e000-76e9e766f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
76e9e766f000-76e9e7670000 r--p 00020000 09:02 2727958                    /lib64/ld-2.12.so
76e9e7670000-76e9e7671000 rw-p 00021000 09:02 2727958                    /lib64/ld-2.12.so
76e9e7671000-76e9e7672000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7d3fc456e000-7d3fc458f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r--p 00000000 0
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it was an error related to Apache buffering module.

Comment: How did you solve this problem..??? I am facing similar issue.. Could you please help.?